# How to get the parent document ID of a subcollection when using CollectionGroup queries?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using collection group query but I'm unable to get the parent document ID.

```
collection
  document1
    subC
      doc1
  document2
    subC
      doc2
```

On running a query I want to get the name of parent document, i.e. `document1`, `document2`, etc but it returns me `doc1` and `doc2`. This is my query:

```dart
var col = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('subC').where('foo', isEqualTo: 'bar');
var snapshot = await col.get();
for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
  print(doc.id); // Prints doc1, doc2
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`doc.id` returns the underlying document ID. You need to first get the current `DocumentReference` (`doc1`, `doc2`), using that get `CollectionReference` (`subC`) and then get its parent which is your `document1` and `document2`.

So, you need this:

```dart
var col = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('subC').where('foo', isEqualTo: 'bar');
var snapshot = await col.get();
for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
  print(doc.reference.parent.parent?.id); // Prints document1, document2
}
```